# How to use form_for of rails in other controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently writing a rails project. There are two model, course and post. What I want is to allow people to add comments(posts) in course's show page. I have a form_for for post, like this:

```
    <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
    <div class="well">
      <h4>PICK a nickname:</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.text_field :user , class: "form-control",  rows: "3"%>
        </div>
        <h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.text_area :content , class: "form-control",  rows: "3"%>
        </div>   
          <%= f.submit "Add New Comment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

How can I use this form_for in course's show html page?
Also, when submitting the post, I want the page to stay at the show page.

Answer (score 0):

1. render as partial from course's show page (but don't forget put @post)

   render partial '/comments/comment', locals: {post:post}
2. use remote true (with right method) / or redirect user back to

   form_for post remote: true, method:'put/post/path'

for redirect back need to know your routes.rb